# Ubuntu 16.10 becomes slow while copying

Tags: 16.10, performance

I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 and when I trying to copy data from one hard drive to another I noticed that Ubuntu becomes extra slow, something that did not happen to me with previous versions like willy werewolf. I have a dual core processor with 4 GB of RAM and graphics card. The version you install is 32-bit.

Will it become slow because when installing Ubuntu I simply install it using "next, next" instead of configuring a swap memory?

Comment: Could you give more details about the CPU in your system.

Comment: @ankit7540 thanks for answer, my procesor is Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5700 @ 3.00GHz × 2

Comment: Your processor is a 64 bit processor. Hence 64bit version of Ubuntu would be best to get full potential of the CPU.

Comment: @ankit7540 Ok but with previous versions like willy werewolf 32bit had not experienced a poor performance, on the contrary, worked quite fast. What could be happening? I made a simple installation like the one that appears in this web https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Every Ubuntu installation should have a swap partition or a swapfile. Your disks could have a partition alignment problem that would cause performance issues on a copy. Please edit your question (please don't paste into the comments) to include the `terminal` output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `free -h`.